# Шлюзование в локальной сети

Tags: веб-сервер, сеть, usergate

Здравствуйте. В организации имеется прокси-сервер UserGate5 (IP=192.168.0.20) для выхода в интернет и несколько локальных сетей. Каждая локальная сеть соединена свичами, а они в свою очередь роутером. Так же имеется внутренний веб сервер (IP=192.168.0.1). Можно ли настроить шлюз таким образом, что бы можно было зайти на прямую из интернета на веб-сервер?

Answer (score 1):

[Публикация ресурсов](http://www.usergate.ru/products/usergate/resource_publishing.php)

[Как настроить NAT и firewall](http://entensys.ru/support/axel/firewall_rules.html)